# how to install and activate libraries numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I used'pip install numpy', it looks like it was installed (if try to install again - Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\pk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (1.19.4)) but when I've tried to use 'import numpy', ***ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' appears***

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: I would check PATH, it sounds like you have installed numpy but when you run a program it can't find the module.

Comment: The packages were installed into the 32-bit directory.  Check your python installation to ensure it’s the 32-bit version. (I presume it is, given where pip installed the pkgs, but worth a check).

Comment: First I installed 32-bit version, but then I installed 64-bit one 'cause my computer is 64-bit. I thought I deleted the 32-bit version, but obviously, some files remained. What should do in that case? How to change way to the right folder?

Comment: Personally, I’d completely uninstall both architectures and start fresh.

Answer (score 2):

try to install all with `pip3 install numpy` etc... 
check if you use python 2.x or 3.x from your IDE

Comment: No need to run `pip3` as the error message states the pkgs were installed into the `python38-32` directory.